# How to open a big text file which is in the format [[skill1, skill2, skill3, ...], [skill1, skill4, skill6, ...], ….] in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, bigdata

How to open a big text file which is in the format

```
[[skill1, skill2, skill3, ...], [skill1, skill4, skill6, ...], ….]
```

in Python. I have tried using Pandas and numpy but read_csv methods or other such methods does not work.

UPDATE: I was able to read the .txt file using the following line of code:

```
f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
print(f.read(5))
```

Comment: The standard csv readings in `panadas` and `numpy` work without the `[]`, expecting clean rows and columns of numbers.  Do you have control over how this file is generated?

Comment: No I don't have control over the generation of the file. It is a dataset given to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you did not mention explicitly that the file contains any linebreaks I would use the following approach. Write some custom Python code to

- load the the file
- search and replace "], [" with "\n"
- search and replace "[" with "".
- save this file on the disk and load it as CSV with "," as separator.

For huge files I'd probably use SED. The following code does the above. It works by reading character by character and checking, what the last read character had been. Based on several ifs I determine the operation to be executed. Note: I only spent a few minutes on this, it might be optimized for sure. The input file does not require to have linebreaks, the output will have them.

```
lastreadchar = ''

with open("data.txt",mode='r') as i, open('out.txt','w') as o:
    while True:
        x = i.read(1)

        if x == '': # end of file has been reached
            break 
        elif x==' ':
            pass
        elif x==']':
            pass
        elif x=='[':
            if lastreadchar == '[': 
                # at the beginning of the file, don't do anything
                pass
            elif lastreadchar == '\n': # a new line
                pass   
            elif lastreadchar == ',': # a new line
                pass
        elif x==',':
            if lastreadchar == ']': # at the beginning of the file
                print('\n')
                o.write('\n')
            else:
                print(x, end='')
                o.write(x)
        else:
            print(x, end = '')            
            o.write(x)

        lastreadchar = x
```

With really big text files (in the multi-GB range) I'd probably use SED to process the file this way.

Comment: How do I load the file? It's taking forever to load it using pandas.

Comment: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

Comment: If you provide a sample of the file I can write a few lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. Works just fine. Can you explain me how do iterate through it to get each values?

Answer (score 1):

You could try reading line by line (if your file is written in line formatin) and append the data.

```
for line in open('yourfile.big'):
    do_something(line)
```

And maybe then you could try saving big (structured) data files like yours in parquet of ORC format

Answer (score 1):

I was able to read the .txt file using the following line of code f = open("demofile.txt", "r") print(f.read(5))

UPDATED ANSWER:What I finally did is:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    mylist = list(f)
    temp = mylist[0]
    l =  temp.split(']')
    l.pop(0)
    for x in range(0,len(l)):
        l[x] = l[x][3:]
        l[x] = l[x].split(', ')
```

The above code finally generated a list inside of list.
So if I access l[0][0] it gives me skill 1.
The data was of the following format [[skill1, skill2, skill3, ...], [skill1, skill4, skill6, ...], ….]

Thoughts?

Comment: Show a sample of the read.  It may be valid list display.  If so it can be `eval`

Comment: @hpaulj A sample of the read generated by (f.read(50)) --> [[], ["Contract Negotiation", "Supply Chain Manage

Comment: read(bytecount) just reads bytecount bytes. How do you know how many to read. Your solutions seems incorrect to me.

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen Please see my Updated answer and then tell if it's better now?

Comment: Looks way better!

Comment: I have added an implementation of my proposal to my answer, seems to work fine

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen Thank you so much. The code seems to be working better now.